# Using a pipeline with RBM and MLP Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a pipeline with an `RBM` and a `MLPclassifier`, my input data will pass first on the rbm, a dimensiality reduction will be made (from 513 features to 100 features (nodes)), I managed to write the code and it seems to be correct but i get this error at the end

> UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and
>   being set  to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 'precision',
>   'predicted', average, warn_for)

```
  precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.00      0.00      0.00        25
      1       0.00      0.00      0.00        28
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00        28
      3       0.00      0.00      0.00        34
      4       0.00      0.00      0.00        25

avg / total       0.00      0.00      0.00       140
```

Here's my code

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, 
Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=100,activation="tanh",max_iter=200)
rbm = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)

classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('mlpclassifier', mlp)])

rbm.learning_rate = 0.06
rbm.n_iter = 20
rbm.n_components = 100

classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print("MLP using RBM features:\n%s\n" % (metrics.classification_report(Y_test,
                                             classifier.predict(X_test))))
```

Comment: This is not an error. Just a warning that for a specific class, no samples were predicted which results in a divide by a zero in precision or recall calculation. If possible add the data so that we can check whats actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Kumar, i tried to take one sample from the test set, and make a prediction

```
print('the real label', Y_train[0])
print('the prediction', classifier.predict(X_train[0].reshape(1,-1)))
```

And that's what i get as an output

```
the real label [1 0 0 0 0]
the prediction [[0 0 0 0 0]]
```

It seems to me that the classifier(Pipeline) is not trained !!

Comment: Have you called `classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)` yet, before predicting the test data?